# How Magento 2 handles images on frontend?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, frontend, magento2

There are many elements in magento 2, where we can attach and insert images.
So, how Magento 2 handles all type of images on frontend ?
How it effect on performance ?
Any help, suggestion, tricks and tips for Magento 2 images handling.

Answer (score 0):

> Media storage helps you organize and gain access to media files that
>   are stored on the server. The path to the location of the files is
>   determined by the Base URL configuration. Files in media storage can
>   be accessed from the editor while working on pages and static blocks.
>   Media storage is usually located in the file system on the same server
>   as the Magento program files.

Alternatively, media files can be managed in a database, or located on a separate server or content delivery network. The editor can be configured to use either static or dynamic media URLs for catalog content in category or product descriptions.

**To upload files to media storage**

The first two steps are the same as if you are inserting an image.

1. On the toolbar of the WYSIWYG editor, click `Insert Image` [image: Insert image icon]
2. After the Image URL field, click `Browse` [image].
3. In the directory tree on the left, do one of the following:

   - Navigate to the folder where you want to save the uploaded image.
   - Navigate to the place where you want to create a new folder and click Create Folder. Then, enter the folder name and click OK.
4. To upload file(s) to media storage, click `Choose Files`. Then, do the following:

   - In the directory of your local computer, navigate to the location of the images.
   - Select each image to be uploaded.
   - Click `Open`.

The images are uploaded to the current media storage folder on the server.

**To insert an image from media storage**

Open the page or block to be edited. Then, use one of the following methods to insert an image from media storage:

**WYSIWYG Mode**

- On the toolbar of the WYSIWYG editor, click on Insert Image... (see point 1)
- After the Image URL field, click the Browse icon (the icon on the right).
- Insert Image (WYSIWYG Mode)

In the directory tree on the left, navigate to the folder where the image is stored.

Select the tile of the image. Then, click Insert File.
[image: Insert file]

**From HTML Mode**

- Position the cursor in the code where the `<img>` tag is to be inserted.
- Click `Insert Image`

[image: Insert Image (HTML Mode)]